# Select distinct rows / valid SQL syntax?

Tags: sql

Is this a valid SQL syntax: `SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN, * FROM TABLE`?

Is this syntax supported by almost all relational database systems?

I want to select all rows which have a distinct column value / foreign key which references the primary key of another table.

I guess it must be a bit more complex, something like:

```
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments = new StringBuilder(256);
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append("SELECT * FROM ");
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append(l_rule.getOldTableName());
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append(" WHERE ");
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append(l_rule.getOldRuleMasterFieldName());
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append(" IN ");
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append("(SELECT DISTINCT ");
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append(l_rule.getOldRuleMasterFieldName());
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append(" FROM ");
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append(l_rule.getOldTableName());
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append(".A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LCCALRECU B WHERE B.LID = A.");
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append(l_rule.getOldRuleMasterFieldName());
l_sbufSelectOldAppointments.append("))");
```

with a Java StringBuilder which builds the query. Thus I'm hopefully getting all rows with distinct `l_rule.getOldRuleMasterFieldName()` values.

Comment: I must admit I don't understand. You will avoid rows which have duplicates on COLUMN ?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is applied over _all columns_, not over just the column the keyword appears beside. Can you explain better with sample tables and a sample output rowset what you want to acheive?

Comment: _all rows which have a distinct column value / foreign key_  sounds like you might just need a simple `INNER JOIN` with a `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: If there is a duplicate column value, how do you want the database to decide which row to choose?

Answer (score 1):

Your `DISTINCT` keyword is unnecessary in your SQL query. In your query that you provided, it should always get the same result regardless of whether you have the `DISTINCT` keyword is placed.

Here's your SQL query, as I understand if from your code:

```
SELECT * FROM OldTableName
 WHERE OldRuleMasterFieldName
 IN
( SELECT DISTINCT OldRuleMasterFieldName
  FROM OldTableName A
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LCCALRECU B WHERE B.LID = A.OldRuleMasterFieldName)
)
```

More generalized, it fits this template:

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable
WHERE justOneField 
  IN ( SELECT DISTINCT oneOtherField FROM ...)
```

If you think about it, the `DISTINCT` does nothing here. It doesn't matter if you deduplicate records that you are using to populate an `IN()` clause.  Membership filtering will be the same.  Example, you live `IN ('France','France','France')` if and only if you live `IN ('France')`.

Simply take out the `DISTINCT`.

```
  IN ( SELECT oneOtherField FROM ...)
```

Comment: Thanks yeah, you're right, but I think it's still not right? I would basically select all rows from OldTableName which have a foreign key set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes try this query

```
SELECT "DISTINCT COLUMN" FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

No - the syntax is not valid in all RDBMS's

A quick `SqlFiddle` shows that `SqlServer` and `Postgres` do support this, but not `MySql` nor `Oracle`

- Postgres : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/39226/1
- SqlServer : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29768/1

(SqlFiddle won't allow bookmarking of invalid queries, but you just toggle the RDBMS drop down and execute)

Comment: MySQL accepts `SELECT DISTINCT SomeColumn, Sometable.* FROM SomeTable` without error, though not sure how meaningful the output is.

Comment: Indeed, as does Oracle (AFAIK Oracle always requires table level qualification of `*` when used in conjunction with one or more explicitly named columns). The readability and expressiveness of what `SELECT DISTINCT *` is trying to convey would grind me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by Oracle for example. You are saying: give me all fields plus a column. But then "all" would be all plus the column, and "all plus the column" would hence mean all plus the column plus the column. And so on. Well at least I guess this would be the argument. What you *can* do, however, is to get all columns of a particular table plus any additional columns (which can be from the same table):

```
select distinct mycol, mytable.* from mytable;
```

BTW: Distinct makes no sense here, but I guess you know that. EDIT: Sorry, I just noticed I skipped the lower part of your request. So you **don't know**. Distinct gives you distinct result records. Once records have an id for example they are distinct by definition and distinct is superfluous. Think about what columns you want to compare for uniqueness and what columns you want to show. Maybe you are rather looking for GROUP BY or an EXISTS clause?